# Create Out of office calendar events with Google Script Api that auto decline meetings

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

In the Google Calendar, it is possible to create an "Out of Office" event that automatically decline all future invitation for the set event.
[image: Event create through UI]

I'm trying to create this type of event using the Google script api, but I somehow don't manage to.

So far, I'm stuck at writing this:

```
function createOutOfOffice(date){
  var startDate = new Date(date);
  startDate.setHours(0,0,0,0);
  var endDate = new Date(startDate);
  endDate.setDate(startDate.getDate() + 1);

  var outOfOffice = CalendarApp.createEvent('Out of office', startDate, endDate);
  outOfOffice.setVisibility(CalendarApp.Visibility.PUBLIC);
  outOfOffice.removeAllReminders();
}
```

But it does not create a true Out of office event, but generates a good old all day event instead:

[image: Event created through the API]

I'm obviously missing something there, as my created event won't **auto decline** meetings.

Reading through the [api documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-event), I don't find anything obvious to help me achieve what I want.
Is it even remotely possible to do so with Google App Scripts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Out of Office event is a rather new feature of Google Calendar and thus, unfortunately it has not been implemented in Google Apps Script or Google API yet. You can see [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/122674818) that a respective feature request has been filed on Issuetracker already. You can give it a star to increase visibility, so that the feature will hopefully be implemented soon.

Comment: Is this Out of Office event feature implemented now? if not, is there any other ways to achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

It's been implemented in late 2023. You have to use the calendar service in order to access the API; the `CalendarApp` won't allow out-of-office events.

```
const event = {
    summary: 'Title',
    // "description" parameter is not allowed
    start: {
      dateTime: startTime.toISOString(),
    },
    end: {
      dateTime: endTime().toISOString(),
    },
    eventType: 'outOfOffice',
    outOfOfficeProperties: {
      autoDeclineMode: 'declineOnlyNewConflictingInvitations',
      declineMessage: 'Out of Office',
    },
    transparency: 'opaque',
};

var e = Calendar.Events.insert(event, 'CALENDAR_ID');
```

Reference: https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/guides/calendar-status?hl=en#create-out-of-office